# Google Chart is shown NgDirective, but not NgComponent

Tags: dart, google-visualization, angular-dart

I'm having issues with showing `Google Graphs` in an `AngularDart` component, but not in an `AngularDart` directive. For the code below the graph is nicely displayed for the `directive`, where the `div` node has had two `divs` added as children to contain the graph and SVG. But for the `compoenent`, the graph is not shown, but in the DOM the same divs appear as children. Any ideas of how to debug this or solutions for it?

Running the code below prints out to console both `Succesfully printed plot for Component graph` and `Succesfully printed plot for Directive graph`.

The simplest code to showcase it is:

`main.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;

import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

void printPlot(dom.Element element, String title) {
  var gviz = js.context.google.visualization;

  var gTableData = new js.Proxy(gviz.DataTable);
  gTableData.addColumn('number', 'Size');
  gTableData.addColumn('number', 'Counts');

  gTableData.addRow(js.array([1, 2]));
  gTableData.addRow(js.array([3, 4]));

  var options = js.map({
      'title': title
  });

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var chart = new js.Proxy(gviz.ScatterChart, element);
  chart.draw(gTableData, options);
  print("Succesfully printed plot for $title");
}

@NgComponent(selector: '[my-component]')
class MyComponent {
  final dom.Element element;
  MyComponent(this.element) {
    js.context.google.load('visualization', '1', js.map({
        'packages': ['corechart'],
        'callback': (() => printPlot(element, 'Component graph'))
    }));
  }
}

@NgDirective(selector: '[my-directive]')
class MyDirective {
  final dom.Element element;
  MyDirective(this.element) {
    js.context.google.load('visualization', '1', js.map({
        'packages': ['corechart'],
        'callback': (() => printPlot(element, 'Directive graph'))
    }));
  }
}

@NgController(selector: '[controller]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl')
class Controller {
  Controller() {
  }
}

class DashboardModule extends Module {
  DashboardModule() {
    type(Controller);
    type(MyComponent);
    type(MyDirective);
  }
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new DashboardModule());
}
```

`index.html`

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body controller>
<div my-component></div>
<div my-directive></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very probably due to the shadowDOM introduced by the NgComponent.
When the JavaScript library doesn't support shadowDOM (which it probably doesn't) it just won't find your DOM elements and therefore can't act on them.
The AngularDart team is working on someone similar to NgComponent but without shadowDOM (which is currently not possible). But this is in experimental state only (as far as I know) and no release date available.